# SharePoint 2013 - Manage User Profiles - Not Showing Profiles in Search

Tags: 2013, search, user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I did the full import from AD and I have around 1100+ profiles. (See Screen shot)

However when I search via my domain name (i.e. mydc) I don't see any results. My login goes as mydc\ahmed

[image]

[image]

What am I missing??

Comment: Your screen shot says you are searching for `ahmed`

Comment: Updated my question. I have a lot of users in the name of Ahmed and Mohamed and Muhammedh

Comment: did you select the "Profiles Missing from Import" and see if these profiles are miss? number of imported profiles are equal to the Number of User in AD( which u trying to import)

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Tried both. Cudnt even see a single profile :(

Comment: What happens if you search for the first letter of your domain?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I don't see any results.

Comment: Left it over the weekend and now it's showing up. I dnt know what fixed it.